# Remove "Translated Meesage Bar" from top

Tags: html, google-translate

Once Google has finished the translation it shows a bar on top of the website which ruins my website's look! I dont know how to disable it! Guide me please! This is a HTML website.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxFw9.png)

Comment: if you are using html5 you can go for padding or margin alignments @graphicdeveloper

Comment: what exactly do you mean by that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this code will hide the "revert to original" bar after translation!

```html
<style>.goog-te-banner-frame.skiptranslate {
    display: none !important;
    } 
body {
    top: 0px !important; 
    }</style>
```